# List of object constants

Tags: c#, list

I have a class "Process", where the "Exams" property is a List of the Exam class.

```
public class Process
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Person? Person { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Must select at least one exam")]
    public List<Exam>? Exams { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]  // Ensure that the date is in the correct format
    public DateTime ProcessDate { get; set; }
}

public class Exam
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get;}
    
    [Required]
    public string? Name { get;}

    public Exam(int id, string name) 
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

My idea is to have a class or something that has all possible exams and make sure that the objects inside Process.Exams belong to this set of possible exams.

```
static class PossibleExams
{
    static readonly Exam exam1 = new Exam(1, "Exam 1");
    static readonly Exam exam2 = new Exam(2, "Exam 2");
    static readonly Exam exam3 = new Exam(3, "Exam 3");
    static readonly Exam exam4 = new Exam(4, "Exam 4");
    static readonly Exam exam5 = new Exam(5, "Exam 5");
}
```

I know that the code like this does not work. I'm not proficient enough in C# for making this. I feel that the solution is pretty simple but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: It would be possible with reflection, but I don't think that is really necessary for your situation. Why don't you just define a static readonly array in the `PossibleExams` class which holds all possible exams?

Comment: "I know that the code like this does not work." What exactly does not work? Would a static read-only list of exams work better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a private constructor to ensure no other Exam is created than the one from your list:

```
public class Exam
{
    public static Exam Exam1 = new (1, "Exam 1");
    public static Exam Exam2 = new (2, "Exam 2");
    public static Exam Exam3 = new (3, "Exam 3");
    public static Exam Exam4 = new (4, "Exam 4");
    public static Exam Exam5 = new (5, "Exam 5");
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    private Exam(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

This pattern can be useful as a sort of extended Enum.

This pattern is probably not useful if you want to store your exams in a database or a file, since they would could no longer be restricted to your specific set of exams. You could maybe store an Id for the exam instead, and add a `public static Exam FromId(int id)` method, and throw an exception for invalid Ids, but it will depend on your specific use case.

Comment: I think this a simple solution that works! Thank you!